# Check Null value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting string email is (null).

I am using this code

```
if(email==(id) [NSNull null] || [email length]==0 || [email isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSLog(@"hello");
}
if ([email length] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"hello");
}

if ([email isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    NSLog(@"my");
}
```

I am not get any log.How we check the null value in string. I am stuck.

Comment: You need to check for `nil`.  This is different from checking for NSNull or a "null string".

Comment: When you see `(null)` in an NSLog output that means that the object pointer that was logged with `%@` was `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for (null) just via

```
if (email == nil) {
    NSLog(@"null2");
}
```

or just

```
if (!email) {
    NSLog(@"null1");
}
```

The `NSNull` class is there to put null values inside collections that normally use null as a terminator symbol. See the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/index.html) for further details on the `NSNull` class.

Comment: There is a difference between `nil` and `NSNull`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: So, why did you say "null"?

Comment: Because OP is getting `(null)` and there is something like `NULL` too.

Comment: When NSLog displays `(null)`, that means that it has been passed a `nil` pointer value.  Yeah, it's kind of silly that it doesn't log `(nil)`, but there are lots of problems with NSLog.

Comment: exactly! that is why you should check for nil as my answer says - i don´t get your point.

Comment: My point is that you used the wrong terminology.  You "fixed" the user this one time, but he still doesn't know what he's doing.

Comment: Okay, i disagree. I showed him what the right way was and that what he used has another functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the code that creates that email string object can return an NSNull object (i.e. it's coming from NSJSONSerialization), the simplest way to check if you've got a non-nil, non-empty string is

```
if (email.length) {
    NSLog(@"Got an email address");
}
```

If it can be NSNull, you should use

```
[email isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]
```

to check its type first and then check its length